# Magento2.3.2: Class ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\AddressType does not exist

Tags: magento2.3.2, class-not-found

I am working on Magento2.3.2.

When I tried to access the customers from the admin panel, I am getting the following error.

> Class ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\AddressType
>   does not exist

1. I have already removed the Shipper module from my website.
2. I ran the compile and re-index and cache commands also.

But still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to `eav_attribute` table in database and search **ShipperHQ\Shipper\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\AddressType** this in **backend_model**, if you will get any records there then please remove unnecessory attribute or just update Backend model there.

Hope this solution works for you!